# Is Sorgenfrey topology generated by interval $[a,b)$ with a being irrational, $b$ being rational

Tags: general-topology, sorgenfrey-line

So the aim is to show that for any open set of Sorgenfrey topology, such open set can be expressed as any union of $[a,b)$, given a being irrational and b rational.

How do we show this? or disprove that $\{[a,b)| \text{ a irrational, b rational}\}$ is not a basis for Sorgenfrey Topology.

Comment: How would you express $[0,1)$ as a union of those $[a, b)$ with $a$ irrational, $b$ rational?

Answer (score 0):

$[0,1)$ is Sorgenfrey open, but not equal to a union of intervals $[a_i, b_i)$, $i \in I$ where all $a_i$ are irrational. If $0 \in [a_i, b_i)$ then $a_i < 0$ (we have $a_i \le 0$ and $a_i \neq 0$) and we'd have points outside $[0,1)$ in the union..

So the mentioned collection is *not* a base for the Sorgenfrey line.

Comment: Hi professor, could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4267939/is-any-monomorphism-f-bbb-rk-rightarrow-bbb-rn-for-k-le-n-a-closed-map?noredirect=1#comment8878970_4267939) please? Forgive the bother.