# Is any monomorphism $f:\Bbb R^k\rightarrow\Bbb R^n$ for $k\le n$ a closed map?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples, topological-vector-spaces

So in the text *Functional Analysis* by Walter Rudin the proposition 1.21 states

> *If $n$ is a positive integer and $Y$ is an $n$-dimensional subspace of a complex topological vector space $X$, then every isomorphism of $C^n$ onto $Y$ is a homeomorphism and $Y$ is a closed set*

So if $f:\Bbb R^k\rightarrow\Bbb R^n$ for $k\le n$ is a monomorphism (i.e. a linear injective map) then $f\big[\Bbb R^k\big]$ is a $k$-linear subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ and in particular the above theorem implies that $f$ is a homemorphism between $\Bbb R^k$ and $f\big[\Bbb R^k\big]$ because any monomorphism is an isomorphism onto its image: so finally we conclude that $f$ is a closed map because $f\big[\Bbb R^k\big]$ is closed in $\Bbb R^n$ and so any closed set in $f\big[\Bbb R^k\big]$ is even a closed set in $\Bbb R^n$. Obviously the theorem is enunciated for complex topological vector spaces but when I studied it sometimes ago it seemed to me that it was even valid for real topological vector spaces but I can not be sure now about. So are my argumentations correct? Otherwise is $f$ a closed map? So could someone help me, please?

Comment: The proposition talks about complex topological spaces, so it doesn't really seem to apply. However, the rest is true.

Comment: Well, I studied some times ago the mentioned theorem and it seems to me that it is valid for real space too but honestly I can not be absolutely sure about now. So could you say something about?

Comment: Every linear subspace of a finite-dimensional vector space is closed.

Comment: It seems to work perfectly. But I guess there are more elementary ways to prove that $f$ is closed. For instance, every linear map between finite dimentional vector spaces is continuous. Then you only have to show that the image is closed, and this is true because, given a subspace $V$ of $\mathbb R^n$, first you find an orthonormal base of V, then you complete it to an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb R^n$, and finally $V$ is the orthogonal of the span of vectors that completed the base of $V$, thus it is closed

Comment: @LorenzoPompili Oh, yeah: you want means that if the dimension of $V$ is $k$ then $V$ is the image of $\Bbb R^k\times 0^{n-k}$ via a homeomorphism of $\Bbb R^n$ in $\Bbb R^n$, right?

Comment: However it seems to me that if $ f $ were not an isomorphism this would be irrelevant so we need Rudin's theorem to prove the result but I can be sure about. So what can you say about?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro So (I might be a bit confused by all of this because is low level proofs and I am not sure on what I am allowed to use XD), my idea is: if you take for granted that any linear map between finite dimensional vector spaces is continuous (here I don’t care about the norms, since they are all equivalent, thus it is enough to prove this in the Euclidean case), you can say that the inverse of $f\colon \mathbb R^k\to Im(f)\subset\mathbb R^n$ is continuous (as it is a well defined linear map), where I am giving $Im(f)$ the norm induced by $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: You can do the same for $f$ itself with the same norms/topologies. So you have that $f$ is a homeomorphism. Then, as the OP suggests, you just have to prove $Im(f)$ is closed, and you might do that as you have written for instance.

Comment: I am saying all of this just because that theorem is meant to be used for infinite-dimentional vector spaces, so it seems a little too overkill to use in this setting. The most powerful thing that is needed to prove that $f$ is closed is just the fact that all norms are equivalent in the finite-dimensional setting. Then I may agree on the fact that the above proposition is not so difficult to prove after all, it’s just a matter of invoking elementary facts whenever possible (just my opinion on this question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result Rudin states for complex vector spaces also holds for real ones (IIRC, the local compactness of the field is the important thing, not the fact that $\Bbb C$ is algebraically closed or something along those lines, see Bourbaki's text I think).

So indeed if $f: \Bbb R^k \to \Bbb R^n$ is a linear monomorphism, it is a closed map and $f[\Bbb R^k]$ is some $k$-dimensional linear subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ (which are always closed anyway, we don't need heavy theorems for that, as it's the intersection of zero-sets of a functional (which are all continuous on  $\Bbb R^n$)).

Comment: Okay, it is clear that it is not necessary to use Rudin's theorem to prove that $f\big[\Bbb R^k\big]$ is a closed set; however it seems to me that if $f$ were not an isomorphism this would be irrelevant so that apparently we need Rudin's theorem to prove the result but effectively it is not necessary, as Lorenzo Pompili showed in the comment above, right? Anyway if I like I can use Rudin's theorem to prove the result, although it could be appear sofisticated, right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Whatever gets you the thing you need. As long as you quote the source. Maths is not about seeming sophisticated but about truth and precision.

Comment: Oh, yeah: you said good! I used the adjective *sofisicated* only because the user Lorenzo Pompili leds me to believe this but I think it is simple besides correct, that's all. Anyway thanks very much for your assistance !!! See you soon.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro The proof is simple and correct, no question about it XD Mine was just a point of view that is more related to the following rule of thumb. If you just need to prove things, then just use the most powerful tools you know. If you instead are in the process of learning something (in math), it is often good to test your knowledge and try to do exercises and prove things using elementary tools. But this doesn’t necessarily apply to you… I don’t want to convince you that your proof is “too” sofisticated, because I don’t know what you want to do with that.

Comment: Anyway, the main reason for my comment was to show the “elementary way” just because I find interesting that the essence of the problem reduces to the fact that all the norms on finite dimentional vector spaces over $\mathbb R$ (and $\mathbb C$) are equivalent. (Actually, we don’t even need this for your statement if we are using the Euclidean norms, I was thinking more about two generic finite dim. normed spaces).

Comment: @LorenzoPompili I completely approve your first comment here: I needed these results for other aims.